# How perform nested for loop on list(object) variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I'm writing a terraform module accepts a `list` of entities and each `entity` associates with a list of aliases. I'm having an issue to access alias object and pass in `each.key`. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
resource "vault_identity_entity_alias" "alias" {
  provider = vault.this

  for_each = [
    for entity in var.entities : {
      for alias in entity.aliases :
      alias.name => alias
    }
  ]

  name           = each.key
  mount_accessor = lookup(vault_auth_backend.b[each.key], "accessor", null)
  canonical_id   = vault_identity_entity.entity[each.value.entity].id
}
```

Variable definition

```
variable "entities" {
  description = "A collection of entities where each entity is associated with a list aliases "
  type = list(object({
    name     = string
    policies = list(string)
    metadata = map(string)
    aliases = list(object({
      name      = string
      entity    = string
      auth_path = string
      type      = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

Terraform output

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on .terraform/modules/vault_dba_entity/main.tf line 9, in resource "vault_auth_backend" "b":
   9:   for_each = [
  10:     for entity in var.entities : {
  11:       for alias in entity.aliases :
  12:       alias.name => alias
  13:     }
  14:   ]

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As error message says, `for_each` accepts map or set, thus you have to convert array of objects into a map. Common way of doing it is creating flat array of objects first and then convert it into a map. It can be done by using [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html) function. For better readability I put it into a local variable, but it also can be done inline:

```
locals {
  entities = flatten([
    for entity in var.entities: [
      for alias in entity.aliases: {
        entity_name = entity.name
        alias_name = alias.name
        alias_entity = alias.entity
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Variable `local.entities` would contain list of objects, for example:

```
[
  {
    "alias_name" = "alias1"
    "entity_name" = "object1"
    "alias_entity" = "entity alias1"
  },
  {
    "alias_name" = "alias2"
    "entity_name" = "object1"
    "alias_entity" = "entity alias2"
  },
]
```

Now it's easy to convert it into a map. We just need to pick up unique key to use as an index. Based on your question, alias name should be unique, so it could be done like this:

```
resource "vault_identity_entity_alias" "alias" {
  provider = vault.this

  for_each = {
    for item in local.entities: item.alias_name => item
  }

  name           = each.key
  mount_accessor = lookup(vault_auth_backend.b[each.key], "accessor", null)
  
  # Note, we reference alias_entity, because it was defined with this name
  # in local variable.
  canonical_id   = vault_identity_entity.entity[each.value.alias_entity].id
}
```